# Setting value in mat-slider

Tags: angular, angular-material

How to set an initial value on the angular range slider?

According to the [Angular material documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/slider/overview), the code should be like this:

```html
<mat-slider min="1" max="5" step="0.5" value="1.5">
  <input matSliderThumb>
</mat-slider>
```

However, it does not seem to set a default value.

Here is the stackblitz provided by the angular documentation, with the attributes added: https://stackblitz.com/edit/7nqkex?file=src%2Fexample%2Fslider-overview-example.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `input` inside the`mat-slider`, so you should put the value there, not to `<mat-slider>`.

Try this:

```html
<mat-slider min="1" max="5" step="0.5">
  <input matSliderThumb value="1.5" />
</mat-slider>
```

Comment: This was the solution to my problem!